How can I boost the precedence of an Antlr4 parser branch?
I created the following grammar:
grammar Test;

COMMA: ',';
OPEN: '(';
CLOSE: ')';

ATOM: [0-9a-zA-Z_]+;
SPACE: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;

start: expr EOF;

expr
    : ATOM                                         # Identifier
    | expr OPEN (expr (COMMA expr)*)? CLOSE        # Call
    | OPEN expr CLOSE                              # Wrap
    | expr COMMA expr                              # Then
    ;

And then I tried parsing
FUNC(1, (2, 3), 4)

But it gave me this result
start:
    expr:
        expr "FUNC"
        "("
        expr:
            expr:
                expr "1"
                ","
                expr:
                    "("
                    expr:
                        expr "2"
                        ","
                        expr "3"
                    ")"
            ","
            expr "4"
        ")"
    <EOF>

instead of
start:
    expr:
        expr "FUNC"
        "("
        expr "1"
        ","
        expr:
            "("
            expr:
                expr "2"
                ","
                expr "3"
            ")"
        ","
        expr "4"
        ")"
    <EOF>

How can I make the parser prefer the Call branch over the Then one?
(I feel like * in Antlr4 is more like *? in regular expressions, is it true?)

Try getting rid of the right recursion.

I ended up removing ambiguities altogether:

I allowed the Then branch to have N expressions
I created a new parser node called block that will represent multiple expression sequences
I removed the Then branch as it is now represented by block
I explicitly specified where a block is allowed inside of expressions

grammar Test;

COMMA: ',';
OPEN: '(';
CLOSE: ')';

ATOM: [0-9a-zA-Z_]+;
SPACE: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;

start: block EOF;

block: expr (COMMA expr)*;

expr
    : ATOM                      # Identifier
    | expr OPEN block? CLOSE    # Call
    | OPEN block CLOSE          # Wrap
    ;


I never understood why you had THEN in the first place.

Because I wanted that syntax to be usable anywhere as an expression, but then I realised that even by specifying it manually everywhere that I want to allow it I still handle all the cases
